# How do I match and clear sequences 3 adjacent coloured blocks?

Tags: pygame, grid, puzzle

I'm making a game with elements of a match-3 puzzler (such as *Columns*, *Bejeweled* or *Tetris Attack*).  I don't know where to begin creating an efficient algorithm for matching and clearing.

My assumptions:

- Blocks of a like color can be matched horizontally, vertically, or diagonally in sets of *at least* 3.
- Blocks are held within a grid.  They do not move horizontally.
- However, blocks *do* move vertically due to gravity.
- This is an action game, therefore we have to check up on the grid each frame.
- Due to the design of my game, however, we only need to check for matches if at least one block was falling in the previous frame.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a block moves, add it to a list that needs checking.

When you check a block remove it from the list.

First, decide if lines of 4+ count and if not, which set of 3 takes precedence in a row of 4.

Have your algorithm check in 4 directions instead of 8. (Horizontal, Vertical, and 2 diagonal)

Assuming you first check horizontally and allow matches of 4:

- Look at the block to the left. If it matches increase the # of matched blocks from 1 to 2.
- Keep looking left until you find a block that does not match or the edge of your playing area.
- Then, look to the right and continue adding in the same manner until you find an unmatched block.
- If the number of matched blocks from both directions is greater than 3, then mark the blocks for deletion/exploding.
- Repeat for the other 3 directions.
- Delete all of the blocks marked for deletion.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thanks!  How do programmers come up with these sorts of things?